# Mighty Knight Makes only Minimal Moves

Tags: no-computers, chess

Mighty Knight(regular chess moves only) is trapped in corner cell H1.

What are the minimum number of moves needed for the Knight to visit each X marked cells?

Example: F2..1.   D1...2. Etc

Final individual Values need to be given for only for X marked cells only.

[image]

Comment: Edited to clarify..to each X marked cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a complete map of the minimum number of moves it takes for the knight to get from the top right corner to any square on the board:

> [image: knight map]
>   This was found by manually doing a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search): marking all the 1-step spaces, then the 2-step spaces, then the 3-step spaces, and so on.

Comment: But I mentioned ..no computers

Comment: @Uvc Yes, I did it manually. The only automation involved was the coloring, to make the answer look nice.

Comment: Doing it all at once is much more efficient than doing every marked cell individually.

Comment: Probably..but If I asked for the whole map..people will complain, it is lot of work..this way, they can choose their own way

Comment: @Uvc Yes, the question *is* a lot of work, which is why it's probably not a good question. I don't think there's anything interesting here. There aren't any "aha moments": it's either trial and error, or a bunch of boring work.

Comment: Not really..if you understand the strategy < 10 mt..if not you can spend lot of time..

Comment: I also thought the question was the shortest path to to visit all points (like hexomino).

Comment: @Uvc I know I've misinterpreted the question below but I think Deusovi's approach is the cleanest way to solve the actual problem. It requires just one pass through of the board and can be done by hand.

Comment: I think it is more of my being not clearly conveying exactly wahat I am expecting..I always try to introduce new concepts. Thro puzzles.sometimes I miss the mark..especially min moves puzzled me..some of the numbers are counterintuitive..

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if optimal but I've managed to do it in

> $19$ moves

As follows

> [image]

Comment: I am sorry if I did not make it clear...to each cell

Comment: @Uvc Hexomino has moved the knight to each x marked cell.

Comment: Hope I clarified in the edit..how many minimum moves to A1?  How many min moves to A8 etc for all the X marked cells only...if you weretodo for all the cells, you will get min move Map for the Knight in H1.

Comment: @Uvc So, this is just nine independent questions, effectively?

Comment: Yes.............min moves of course depend on the Knight position.

Comment: Even though it wasn't the original question very nice job hexomino. I think this is optimal.

Comment: All my earlier Knight problems were from beginning to end move trace, it was natural for people to assume so..in retrospect, I should have clearly mentioned..main thing I wanted to show how counterintuitive the map is..g2..4. H5..2?  A8..max ..expected